# Memory leak when working with ABAddressBook and ABRecordRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, abaddressbook

I try to load some specific contacts from address book and store ABRecordRef into a mutable array of dictionaries. I'm using ARC and here is my method:

```
- (ABRecordRef) findContactsMatchingFullName:(NSString *)contactFullName
{
    ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreateWithOptions(NULL, NULL);
    NSArray *allRecords = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab));
    NSCharacterSet *space = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
    NSMutableArray *contactsMutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSDictionary *contact;

    NSUInteger numberOfContacts = allRecords.count;
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfContacts; i++)
    {
        ABRecordRef record = (__bridge ABRecordRef)(allRecords[i]);
        NSString *fname = ( NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonFirstNameProperty));
        NSString *lname = ( NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonLastNameProperty));
        NSString *mname = ( NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty));
        NSString *organization = ( NSString *)CFBridgingRelease(ABRecordCopyValue(record, kABPersonOrganizationProperty));

        if (fname || lname || mname || organization)
        {
            if (!fname) fname = @"";
            if (!lname) lname = @"";
            if (!mname) mname = @"";
            if (!organization) organization = @"";
            NSString *fullName = [[[[fname stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", mname] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:space] stringByAppendingFormat:@" %@", lname] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:space];


            contact = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       (__bridge id)record, ksABRecordRef,
                       fullName, ksFullName,
                       organization, ksOrganization,
                       nil];
            [contactsMutableArray addObject:contact];
        }
    }

    if (ab) CFRelease(ab);



NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"%K LIKE[CD] %@ OR %K LIKE[CD] %@",
                          ksFullName, contactFullName, ksOrganization, contactFullName];


NSArray *filteredArray = [contactsMutableArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

if (filteredArray.count == 1)
    return (__bridge ABRecordRef)([filteredArray[0] objectForKey:ksABRecordRef]);
else
    return nil;
}

- (void)loadContacts:(NSArray*)contactNames
{
    if (!_contacts)
        _contacts = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    else
        [_contacts removeAllObjects];

    for (NSString* name in contactNames)
    {        
        ABRecordRef contactRecord = [self findContactsMatchingFullName:name]; contacts

        if (contactRecord)
            [_contacts addObject:(__bridge id)contactRecord];
    }
}
```

in `loadContacts` method, after each call to `findContactsMatchingFullName` memory usage will go up a huge amount. Most memory usage happens after this line:

```
NSArray *allRecords = CFBridgingRelease(ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(ab));
```

Shouldn't CFBrigingRelease release retain count of `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople`?

Comment: Yes it should. - Have you tried the Xcode "Analyze" option?

Comment: Are you sure that it is memory leak? May be it is memory allocation that would be released later by ARC logic.

Comment: @Visput It is memory allocation but it won't be released any time and with every call of loadContacts method allocation goes up a huge amount

Comment: @MartinR Yes, No messages at all from Xcode Analyze.

Comment: Try to set @autoreleasepool on findContactsMatchingFullName method call, and check if any changes become.

Comment: @Visput autoreleasepool is not available while using ARC.

Comment: I think when I store some of `ABRecordRef`s from allRecords array into another variable and add that variable to a mutable array, allRecords array can not be released while that mutable array is in memory? Is it?

Comment: Write `@autoreleasepool {}` in source editor. You will be surprised.

Comment: @Visput I used autoreleasepool {} and nothing is changed!

Comment: Did you write in this way: `@autoreleasepool { ABRecordRef contactRecord = [self findContactsMatchingFullName:name];
if (contactRecord) [_contacts addObject:(__bridge id)contactRecord];}`

Comment: @Visput No, I put all codes in findContactsMatchingFullName method inside (at)autoreleasepool { // all codes // }

Comment: The final solution that I could advice is try to use Instruments (Allocations and Leaks). In this way you will see what code results to huge memory allocation. It will help to understand how to prevent this situation.